# 'tuple' object is not callable on my code

Tags: python, object, tuples, callable

```
def make_sequence(seq):
    def filter1(*func):
        new_filter = filter(func, seq)
        return tuple(new_filter)

    def filter_iterator(*func):
        new_seq = tuple(filter(func, seq))
        index = 0

        def next1():
            nonlocal index
            if index >= 0 and index < len(new_seq):
                ele = new_seq[index]
                index += 1
            else:
                index = 0
                ele = new_seq[index]
                index += 1
            return ele

        def reverse():
            nonlocal index
            index -= 1
            if index >= 0 and index < len(new_seq):
                ele = new_seq[index]
            else:
                index = len(new_seq) - 1
                ele = new_seq[index]
            return ele

        return {'next': next1, 'reverse': reverse}

    def reverse():
        return tuple(seq[::-1])

    def extend(new_seq):
        nonlocal seq
        seq += new_seq

    return {'filter': filter1, 'filter_iterator': filter_iterator, 'reverse': reverse, 'extend': extend}


s1 = make_sequence((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
print(s1['filter'](lambda x: x % 2 == 0))
```

When I try to return tuple from fitlter1 I get the error:

> 'tuple' object is not callable.

What I try to do is the filter1 get the argument *args because when I will call filiter1() with nothing function he returns the sequence without change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the  `*` on your `def filter1(func):` try that, I noticed that your parameter is a `*func` with `*` where in fact it is a tuple when you put some arguments on the function, It seems that you do not need the `*`. I think you need to search about [`*args` and `**kwargs`](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/)

I've run it and got this output

```
(2, 4)
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Have a quick sample here why you got that message. Because when you put `*` to a parameter in a function it's data type is a `tuple`.

```
def foo(*args):
    print(args)
    print(type(args))


foo(1)
```

**Output:**

```
(1,)
<class 'tuple'>
```

### Why you are getting the error?

```
filter(func, seq)
```

The `filter` function is expecting that your `func` is a function or at least lambda but it's not, what it actually is , is a `tuple` once you put `*` on your `def filter1(*func)`.

---

So base on what you've said here.

> What I try to do is the filter1 get the argument *args because when I
> will call filiter1() with nothing function he returns the sequence
> without change.

What you can do with your function is

```
def filter1(func=None):
    if callable(func):
        new_filter = filter(func, seq)
        return tuple(new_filter)

    return seq
```

Change your `filter1` function to that and you'll get this.

```
print(s1['filter'](lambda x: x % 2 == 0))
print(s1['filter']())
print(s1['filter'](lambda x: x>2))
```

**Output:**

```
(2, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: yeah i know without * it will work but 
when i try to do print(s1['filter']()) it will say **filter1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'**

Comment: Yes it will throw that error and the reason because in your function `filter1` you have a parameter there or in other words an `argument` that you need to provide on. As you said on your code here `print(s1['filter']())` you are not providing any, the `()` is blank so you need to provide there a function since the parameter there as I see is you're going to put it on the `filter` function.

Comment: i understand why i get error but the mission i need to do is : when i call the key of 'filter' i need to send function to filter my seq or not send noting to filter1 and it not change my seq

Comment: You need to do what? have `*`? `object is not callable` means `tuple` is not callable so it's not a function.

Comment: for example : s1 = make_seq((1,2,3,4,5)),
>>> s1['filter'](lambda x: x>2)
>>>(3,4,5)
>>>s1['filter']() 
>>>(1,2,3,4,5)